# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows not clearing the buffer on second clear

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bash

When I clear the first time in this terminal, it clears the screen. When I scroll up, there is still a buffer, which is expected. The second time I clear, it doesn't clear the buffer. When I scroll up the buffer is still there. Can anyone help me with that?

I don't want to reset the terminal, I don't think. I just want to clear that buffer on the second clear so I can scroll back up to exactly where I want to.

Edit: I have found the thread that suggests setting the cls alias to 'clear && echo -en "\e[3J"'. That's almost what I'm looking for, but I just want it to clear the buffer up until the last clear. Is that in fact the reset command?

Comment: That doesn't work. I have tried clear ; clear, clear && clear, and clear

Comment: Windows 10 on a Surface Pro 4

Comment: Oh, 1803 17134.81